# The best way to mount existing, non-empty directory to LVM

Tags: linux, mount, lvm, disk, volume

I've created logical volume /dev/vg01/lv01. Now I want to mount directory /data to this volume. My question is what's the best way to do this? I don't want to lose data from /data directory. Only thing I want to do is mount /data to /dev/vg01/lv01 not losing any data. Did anybody do this and can share his knowlegde with me?

Comment: you're mixing up what gets mounted and where: you can mount file systems on block devices at directories. Directories do not get mounted on block devices. Problem now is I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve. Without using the word "mount", can you explain what it is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a directory /data with some data. I've created space for it on /dev/vg01-lv01. Now I want to put data from /data on /dev/vg01-lv01 device. In /etc/fstab I've added line: /dev/mapper/vg01-lv01 /data xfs defaults 0 0 and after mount -a I lost my data. My question is who can I do this without losing data from /data directory?

Comment: @Grad : please **edit** your question with the update, comment are hard to read.

Comment: @Grad good news, you didn't lose your data. Bad news: you don't seem to understand what mounting does. Good news: that's possible to explain.

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe you're right. Can you recommend me a source where I could learn more about mounting?

Answer (score 2):

what you did :

```
mount /data
```

this will mount the new filesystem over old `/data` directory, effectively hidding it.

You need to

1. `umount /data` (be sure to `cd /` first on all terminal)
2. `mv /data /data.old`
3. `mkdir /data`
4. `mount /data`
5. `cp -rp /data.old/* /data` (providing you don't have hidden files)

as an alternative, copying data can be done as

```
(cd /data.old ; tar cf - * )| (cd /data ; tar xf - )
```